# Asymptotic behavior of $u_t= u_{xx}+au$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, steady-state

Consider the following one-dimensional reaction-diffusion equation:
$$u_t= u_{xx}+au$$
on $\Omega=(0,1)$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions with $a>0$ and a nonnegative initial condition $u_0$. If $\frac{\sqrt a}{\pi}\notin\mathbb{N}$, the only steady state is the zero solution. Now if $\frac{\sqrt a}{\pi}\in\mathbb{N}$, then all the functions $u_0(x)=B\sin(\pi x)$ are steady state solutions because they satisfy the equation and boundary condition for every value of $B$.

**My question is what is the asymptotic behavior of the solutions?**
Using Mathematica I conjecture that if $a<\pi^2$ then the solutions decay to $0$. If $a>\pi^2$ then the solutions grow to infinity. If $a=\pi^2$, then the solutions seem to converge to a positive steady state function.

Comment: An answer to this question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3323389/steady-states-of-u-t-u-xx-pi2u/3325398#3325398).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the method of separating variable as follows $$u(x,t)=f(t)g(x)$$to solve the PDE.